# Upgrade path for S#arp Architecture 1.9.5 to 2.x?

Tags: s#arp-architecture

I have a fairly large ecommerce site running on S#arp Arch 1.9.5. I just saw that the codebase is up to 2.0.4. First of all, nice one to everyone involved, I thought it was dead in the pan after waiting for 2.x for quite some time (...and Ayende ripping into it).

Is there a recommended upgrade path from 1.9.5 to the latest version? Do I just nuget update-package?

Answer (score 1):

I personally upgraded my instance by download the 2.0.4 package from Github (seen below) and then update it locally. I did not meet any problem. Like you i looked for update suggestion but decided to do it manually.

https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/downloads

I did find 2.0.4 Sharp-architecture package at Nuget however I did not run nuget update-package in my application.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by update locally? Did you just reference the new dlls in your existing project?

Comment: When i said upload locally, I mean migrating reference locally. I also found that using Nuget you can update to new version without any problem.